# ¿Cómo añadir valores de una base de datos a un gráfico en HTML?

Tags: html, c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, charts

tengo esta función en un controlador en C# que devuelve valores de una base de datos en forma de arreglos para insertarlos en un gráfico.

```
public static string[] ObtenerDatos()
    {
        string[] arr_usuarios = new string[15];
        int[] arr_contador = new int[15];
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Aquí va la conexión a la BD");
        SqlDataReader reader;
        string query = "SELECT NombreUsuario, Contador FROM dbo.Usuario";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int x = 0;
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            arr_usuarios[x] = reader[0].ToString();
            arr_contador[x++] = int.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();

        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string usuarios = ser.Serialize(arr_usuarios);
        string contador = ser.Serialize(arr_contador);
        string[] arr = { usuarios, contador };
        return arr;
    }
```

Sin embargo, he intentado llamar dicha función a la vista del sistema, pero el código que estoy usando solamente funciona en aspx, y yo estoy trabajando en cshtml:

```
var usuarios = <%# MenuIntranetController.ObtenerDatos()[0] %>;
var contador = <%# MenuIntranetController.ObtenerDatos()[1] %>;
```

¿Alguno de ustedes sabe cuál es el código que tengo que usar para llamar a dicha función que he creado?

Comment: ¿Estas usando asp.net?

Comment: Sí, es ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar una llamada al controlador en asp.net mvc desde linq lo que tienes que realizar es:

- Un [`ActionResult`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) para recoger la acción.
- Un modelo para guardar el resultado (o un listado de modelos en caso de un resultado múltiple).

Comienzo con el modelo:
Necesitas por lo que veo dos parámetros, así que necesitarías un modelo así:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Contador { get; set;}
}
```

y en el controlador podrías llamarlo así:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ObtenerDatos()
{
    List<Usuario> usuarios = new List<Usuario>();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Aquí va la conexión a la BD");
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string query = "SELECT NombreUsuario FROM dbo.Usuario";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        Usuario aux = new Usuario();
        aux.Nombre = reader[0].ToString();
        aux.Contador = Convert.ToInt32(reader[1].ToString());
        usuarios.Add(aux);
    }
    con.Close();

    //Usamos la librería Newtonsoft.Json para convertirlo a JSON
    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = usuarios,
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };
}
```

Suponiendo que esta función la obtenemos después de que la página cargue la podemos invocar con AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/NombreControlador/ObtenerDatos",
    success: function (data) {
        //Lo que quieras hacer con los datos aqui
    },
    error: function (e, ts, et) {
        alert(ts);
    }
});
```

Si lo que quieres es recibirlo al cargar la vista sería:

```
return View("NombreVista", Usuario);
```

y en la vista lo recoges.